# list in c++ is not empty, but there are no elements to iterate on

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, mutex, pass-by-value

I'm writing a multithreading program in c++. In the program, I used a global map object which contains a pthread_t as key, and a pair as value.
The pair is inserted by value (using make_pair). 
The pair contains list (inserted by value) as the first element. To this list I would like to read from and write to. 
(The second element is pthread_mutex_t.)

Well, I have mutex which I use to control the read & write operations on the list. I could see also that pushing element to the list succeeded.
Anyway, using the list.empty method at thread, let's call it X, I could see that the list is not empty (check with no mutex which doesn't suppose to be a problem  at my specific design). Therefore, I used the mutex to lock the list and to iterate the elements. But - the iteration didn't happen - acting like there are no elements in the list.

Here is a code snippest. By the way, I want to use pthread_t and not another options.

Insertion - I checked, it works:
    ThreadData& data = threadsOutput[my_key];

```
data.first.push_back(std::make_pair<Obj1*, Obj2*>(std::move(key),std::move(value)));
```

Iterating:
    // some code to check if the relevant list is empty

```
// the list is not empty, so running:

ThreadData& data = threadsOutput[my_key];

if (pthread_mutex_lock(&(data.second))) // data.second is the relevant pthread_mutex_t

    return; // not arrives here - lock succeeded


MapResult::iterator it = data.first.begin();

for (; it != data.first.end(); ++it)

{

    //some code - not arrives to this code

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what prevents the map from being modified (and thus invalidating that hot-reference you're toting around) between the time you acquire the reference and the time you actually latch the mutex ?

Comment: "check with no mutex which doesn't suppose to be a problem at my specific design" - what magic design could allow the `empty` method to (a) work correctly and (b) give a usable result when the call it without the mutex held?

Comment: it's not fix this issue - but the general flow of the program works in a way that if the thread missed data (since the thread got wrong answers from empty), this data will be handled later.

Comment: @WhozCraig that's a reference so the data it actually will have the updated data (which is the behaviour I want)

Comment: You can't use `pthread_t` as a key because there is no way to compare them for anything but equality. (And you can only compare them for equality using `pthread_equal`. It is a huge mistake to try to use `<`, `>`, `==`, `!=` and the like on `pthread_t` types because they may be handles.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I implemented a corresponding comparator which uses this function, and the comparator is given to the map container at initialization

Comment: @maorlevi Maps need more than just equality. They need a less than operator. How would you manage that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I thought about that - but it will just give me an invalid order of the threads data - and I don't care at my case from the order. I only need the ability to check equality of the keys. I implemented the operator() which I have seen enough when I supply a custom Comparator

Comment: @maorlevi It will not just give you an invalid order of the threads data. It will break the entire logic of the way a map works. It may be unable to find entries that are in fact in the map. It may add duplicates. It may even fail to compile.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you suggest to use unordered map instead? thanks!

Comment: @maorlevi That won't work. How will you hash them? The only operation you can perform on `pthread_t`'s is to compare them for equality. Whatever you're trying to do, this isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You say that you check whether the list is not `empty()` without the mutex held. But `empty()` is not a thread-safe method. You must not call it while you are (potentially) simultaneously modifying the list in another thread.

Is there any code which removes items from the list? It seems possible that, if the list is not empty, it becomes empty before the list is processed.

Comment: The only thread which removes items from the list is the thread that iterating the list's items. Ok I get that empty is not a thread-safe, but why it suppose to be a problem at this case? This check before the call to lock the mutex is in order to optimize the code, so the mutex will be locked when it really has to. Data may be missed, but it being handled later and it's not part of this problem (I believe so). Thanks!

Comment: You don't really show enough of your code to make any better guesses. Maybe the list you're calling `empty()` on and the list you're iterating over are different lists. Try printing the address of and number of elements in the list as soon as you find it empty, and again just before you iterate over it. And, technically, calling `empty()` when there's concurrent access to the list yields undefined behavior and so _anything_ could happen.